# Adapters for electrical connectors to export FMU (electrical acausal - causal connectors)

Tags: modelica

Are there examples/adaptor models for electrical connectors to export the Modelica (electrical component) models as FMUs?
My electrical machine (motor, generator) models are in Modelica and some of the electrical component models are in Simulink. Therefore I want to export the electrical components from Modelica as an FMU. For electrical components, I am using PowerSystems library but any similar examples (or direction) from any other library would be helpful from which electrical components can be exported as FMUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, see [Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.GenerationOfFMUs](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.GenerationOfFMUs.html) for an example.